# Determining distance between reoccurring characters in text

Tags: java, distance

I am trying to determine the distance between the same letters in a block of text and then store this value.

ex. "the following sentence is my example." for the letter "E" 11,3,3,5,6. and for "one queen? it would be 3,1. Spaces will be omitted.

Sort of like associating the sentence with a number-line and getting the distance between points. I would like to do this in Java.

Comment: "I would like to do this in Java" --> good. Then do it and come back if you have a question.

Comment: just iterate through the String using `charAt()` and you'll be golden.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about do the codez for me

Answer (score 1):

String (indexOf)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Pseudo-code

```
String text = "...", searchText="E";
int index = 0, arrIndex = 0;

text = text.toLowerCase();
text = text.replace(" ", "");
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

int results[] = new int[50];

int prevMatch = text.indexOf(searchText, index);

while(prevMatch != -1) {

    if ((index = text.indexOf(searchText, prevMatch+1)) == -1) {
        break;
    }
    results[arrIndex++] = index - prevMatch;
    prevMatch = index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `split()` method from String class and extract the substrings text length to check the distance. You will need also to `trim()` the substrings to remove the spaces.

Comment: it will misbehave if given character occurs in the end of a string, e. g. `"EaaEEbE".split("E")` will return  `"", "aa", "", "b"` (without `""` at the end)